# C# код в JetBrains Rider наполнен непонятными символами

Tags: c#, unity3d, jetbrains, rider

Код C# скрипта в `JetBrains Rider` почему-то наполнен непонятными символами, похожими на пробелы, но они никак не выделяются. Прошу помочь!

Текстом относительно сложно объяснить, по-этому, проблема продемонстрирована на видео:
https://youtu.be/BbS8GV62WKU.

Из-за этого у меня не работают скрипты в Unity.

Comment: вставьте сюда код из видео, скорее всего у вас просто в райдере просто включена опция "виртуального пробела"

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206916285-Click-anywhere-and-cursor-is-put-there

Comment: Settings -> Editor -> Allow placement of caret after end of line

Comment: В Editor нету такой настройки.

Вот фото всех настроек Editor: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1znietf-IKc5DHEPeujR1wjrkbhu5ZpJ3/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Я нашол эту функцию она находиься в Editor > General